# What are IE8 add-ons useful for web developer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-8

Does **IE 8** have any other good add-ons/extensions/plugins other than "Developer toolbar", which is useful for web developer/designer/tester?

Answer (score 5):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is good tool for debugging and monitoring requests/responses.

Comment: +1. Note that Fiddler can be used as a HTTP proxy (so you can watch/alter any HTTP traffic, not just IE).

Comment: does Fiddler have any usefulness for XHTML CSS layout developer?

Comment: But I'm asking for IE8 add-ons . Fiddler is a standalone tool

Answer (score 2):

I use debugbar and httpwatcher

Comment: what is usefulness of debugbar if i'm already having "IE8 developer toolbar"